# Go to previous state or Re Render component for two different API functions in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios

I have 2 different function which fetches different data from API, so I have separated them to update the data required.

After clicking again on previous menu item (All) element the previous function (updateLanguage) should work or re render the whole component to get the data.

**Below is the API Function**

```
export function fetchPopularRepos(category_id) {
    var encodedURI = window.encodeURI(
      'http://www.mocky.io/v2/5c44710d3200004f00af156bsds'
    );
    return axios.get(encodedURI).then(function(response) {
      return response.data.sub_videos;
    });
}

export function fetchPopularReposUpdated(homepage) {
    var encodedURI = window.encodeURI(
      'http://www.mocky.io/v2/5c5acfb43200007b274ec75dsdsd'
    );
    return axios.get(encodedURI).then(function(response) {
      return response.data.sub_videos;
    });
}
```

**Below is the component code**

```
class Playground extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedLanguage: 'All', // default state
      repos: null
    };
    this.updateLanguage = this.updateLanguage.bind(this);
    this.updateLanguagenew = this.updateLanguagenew.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateLanguage(this.state.selectedLanguage);
  }
  updateLanguage(lang) {
    this.setState({
      selectedLanguage: lang,
      repos: null
    });

    fetchPopularRepos(lang).then(
      function (repos) {
        this.setState(function () {
          return { repos: repos };
        });
      }.bind(this)
    );
  }

  updateLanguagenew(lang) {
    this.setState({
      selectedLanguage: lang,
      repos: null
    });
    fetchPopularReposUpdated(lang).then(
      function (repos) {
        this.setState(function () {
          return { repos: repos };
        });
      }.bind(this)
    );
  }

  render() {
    console.log (fetchPopularRepos);
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.selectedLanguage}</div>
        <SelectLanguage
          selectedLanguage={this.state.selectedLanguage}
          onSelect={this.updateLanguagenew}
        />
        {
        !this.state.repos ? (
          <div>Loading</div>
        ) : (
          <RepoGrid repos={this.state.repos} />
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Below is code to create the menu**

```
function SelectLanguage(props) {
  const languages = [
    'All',
    'Javascript',
    'Ruby',
    'Java',
    'CSS',
    'Python',
    'PHP',
    'Shell'
  ];

  return (
    <ul className="languages">
      {languages.map(lang => (
        <li
          className={lang === props.selectedLanguage ? 'selected' : ''}
          onClick={props.onSelect.bind(null, lang)}
          key={lang}
        >
          {lang}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `updateLanguagenew` method, you can check if the lang selected is `All` and then call updateLanguage method

```
updateLanguage(lang) {
    this.setState({
      selectedLanguage: lang,
      repos: null
    });

    fetchPopularRepos(lang).then(
      function (repos) {
        this.setState(function () {
          return { repos: repos };
        });
      }.bind(this)
    );
  }

  updateLanguagenew(lang) {
    if (lang === 'All') {
        this.updateLanguage(lang);
        return;
    }
    this.setState({
      selectedLanguage: lang,
      repos: null
    });
    fetchPopularReposUpdated(lang).then(
      function (repos) {
        this.setState(function () {
          return { repos: repos };
        });
      }.bind(this)
    );
}
```